# Schedule scrapy spiders to run every N minutes

Tags: python, scrapy

I need help to schedule my spiders runs every N minutes. Early I see most people used `reactor.callLater` and `reactor.run`for this purpose but it seems there is no possibilities to use these functionalities now. How can I schedule it programmaticaly?

```
def run_crawl():
    """
    Run a spider within Twisted. Once it completes,
    wait 5 seconds and run another spider.
    """
    runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())
    runner.crawl(SpiderA)
    runner.crawl(SpiderB)
    deferred = runner.join()
    deferred.addCallback(reactor.callLater, 5, run_crawl)
    return deferred

run_crawl()
reactor.run()
```

At this moment my crawler scheduled by Windows task scheduler, but I want to schedule it programmatically.

Comment: “but it seems there is no possibilities to use these functionalities now” What’s your source? Do you get an error?

Answer (score -1):

You could give a try with an external module named `schedule` :
[schedule github link](https://github.com/dbader/schedule)

Tell me if it doesn't fit your needs.